# Redux-thunk action returns a function, which is not executed, so data is not fetched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a container component that should populate the redux store with item data when it's mounted, the component correctly calls the action with the `id` that was requested. The action returns a `dispatch` function, which is never executed, so data is never retrieved.

What am I doing wrong?

my container component is this:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import fetchItem from "../actions/itemActions";
import ItemDetails from "../components/ItemDetails";

class ItemDetailsContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    item: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetchItem(this.props.match.params.number);
  }

  render() {
    return <ItemDetails {...this.props} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    item: state.item,
    user_location: state.user_location
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemDetailsContainer);
```

my action file looks like this:

```
 import * as actions from "../constants/constants";
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

const itemDetailsRequest = id => {
  return {
    type: actions.FETCH_ITEM_REQUEST,
    id,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  };
};

const itemDetailsSuccess = (id, json) => {
  return {
    type: actions.FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS,
    items: json.map(child => child),
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  };
};

const itemDetailsFailure = (id, json) => {
  return {
    type: actions.FETCH_ITEM_FAILURE,
    error: json.error,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  };
};

const fetchItem = id => {
  console.log(`returning dispatch function for item, id: ${id}`);
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log("fetching Item: " + id);
    dispatch(itemDetailsRequest(id));
    fetch(`item.json?id=${id}`)
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        error => console.log("AN ERROR OCCURED.", error)
      )
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(itemDetailsSuccess(id, json));
      });
  };
};

export default fetchItem;
```

Comment: `fetchItem` returns a function try `fetchItem(this.props.match.params.number)();` to invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the `dispatch` when calling `fetchItem`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  return this.props.dispatch(fetchItem(this.props.match.params.number));
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `dispatch` directly in the `componentDidMount`, you can directly use `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    item: state.item,
    user_location: state.user_location
  };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return({
    fetchItem: (number) => dispatch(fetchItem(number)),
  })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemDetailsContainer);
```

And in the componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  return this.props.fetchItem(this.props.match.params.number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that if I dispatch `fetchItem` the function is indeed executed, but redux expects it to have a `type` property, this is the error I get: `Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?` I tried both your suggestions.

Comment: Can you show me your **constants** file ? When you are facing this error it is either: 1. You don't have a property **type** when you dispatch, 2. The value of **type** is undefined (= The constant you call is not found in your constants file)

Comment: Well spotted, earlier, in order to test, I moved the specific constants for these actions to a separate constants file, but I failed to change the import to the new name.. thanks, this bit works now.